# REST API and ACLs - should the API return contacts made accessible via an ACL?

Tags: api, rest

My REST API call returns data fine as long as the user has 'view all contacts' permission. But if I turn that off and instead grant the user access to a particular group via an ACL, I get nothing. I've confirmed that the user can see the relevant data through the UI.

*Should* that work? Or are ACLs not taken into account by the REST API?

Using WordPress and Civi 4.5.8.

Update 1: [this issue](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=35107.0) on the forum suggests it might not be WordPress specific.

Update 2: Just to clarify exactly what I'm doing, here's the relevant part of the URL:

/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/extern/rest.php?entity=Contact&action=get&api_key=xxx&key=xxx

I can get the data I want by using the API key of an admin, or if a non-admin has 'View all contacts' permission. But I get no results if the non-admin lacks this permission and only has access via an ACL. (If I change the API key I get an authentication error, so I'm confident that's correct.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the Contact Get REST api is triggered, I can see that the permission clause for the ACL is being generated from the `whereClause()` funcion of [`CRM_ACL_API`](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/ACL/API.php#L122). Here a `contactId`(previously [passed as NULL](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php#L4680)) is fetched from the session (logged in user id) and the contact from `api_key` is **actually** not taken into account. Hence a 0 is set for `ContactId` and ACL permissions are not respected.

Comment: Exactly what I needed to know - thanks! Now to see if I can fix it...
(will assign bounty as soon as I can - StackExchange says I need to wait six hours)

Answer (score 0):

I tested this locally & it worked fine - but looking at the wordpress code the signature of the loadBootStrap function does not match the signature of drupal (which works).

I expect it's not responding correctly to

```
  CRM_Utils_System::loadBootStrap(array('uid' => $uid), TRUE, FALSE);
```

Since

return $config->userSystem->loadBootStrap($params, $loadUser, $throwError, $realPath);

passes in an array but WP seems to be unable to cope with that